# spark dataframe collect malforming data that contains commas

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am attempting to perform a collect on a dataframe, however my data contains commas and is malforming the output object, resulting in more columns then expected (split by each comma).

My dataframe contains the data:

```
col_a    |col_b
------------------
1,2,3,4,5|1
2,3,4    |2
```

I then perform this:

```
val ct = configTable.collect()
ct.foreach(row => {
  println(row(0))
})
```

Output is -

```
1
2
```

When it should be the string -

```
1,2,3,4,5
2,3,4
```

How do I get the expected results?

Comment: please post how you construct  `configTable`

Comment: @bekce `val configTable = spark.sql("select col_a, col_b from db.table")`

Comment: Hi @jayjay93, two things. First if you want to add more information to your question please **edit** it - instead of adding a comment. Second, I am sure the idea of bekce was that you provide us with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - saying you get the `DF` from a query don't help us a lot, because we don't have access to such table... if you could provide any way to create that table that would be great. _(Bonus with Spark questions usually it help a lot to provide Spark/Scala version, and any other info related e.g. the table is from Hive or a memory only table from other DF)_